# Relation definition is recursive, does not make sense

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, recursion

Apart from the standard definition of a relation, Recently read this one in a book:

Let E and F be two sets.

A relation $τ$ can also be viewed as
a function
from $E$ to $P(F)$  by setting,

for each $x ∈ E$,

$τ (x) = \{{y ∈ F | (x, y) ∈ τ\}}$

I am not able to understand this recursive definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definition is not recursive, it is just badly notated.

If $\tau \subseteq E \times F$ is a relation, define a function $f_\tau : E \to 2^F$ by

$f_\tau(x) = \{ y ~|~ (x,y) \in \tau \}$

Here $2^F$, as usual, denotes the powerset of $F$

**Edit:** here's a small example:

Say $E = \{ a,b,c \}$, $F = \{ x,y \}$, 
$\tau = \{ (a,x), (a,y), (b,x), (c,y) \}$.

Then: 
$$f_\tau(a) = \{ x,y \}$$
$$f_\tau(b) = \{ x \}$$
$$f_\tau(c) = \{ y \}$$

---

Hope this helps! ^_^

Comment: Got it, also but for every $x$, there can be many $y$ in set $F$ in relation $\tau$.

Comment: Happy to help! If this answered your question, please mark it as such so that others on the site know it has been answered ^_^

Comment: There seems to be a problem, if $y \in 2^F$ then $(x,y) \in \tau$ is not possible.

Comment: $y$ belongs to $F$! The entire set $\{ y ~|~ (x,y) \in \tau \}$, however, is a subset of $F$, and is thus an element of $2^F$

Comment: I'll add a small example to clarify ^_^

Comment: Got it, the function value is a set, and not an element, and that set happens to be a subset of the powerset of F

Comment: Almost! Subsets of $F$ are elements of $2^F$. Other than that you've got it ^_^

Comment: Also how do you find/fight bad/ambiguous notation in a textbook?

Comment: At the beginning - exactly like you did. Ask questions whenever you're confused, and people will help and explain where the notation comes from. As you improve, and you see what kinds of notation people tend to abuse, you'll start seeing what people really mean for yourself. It's all experience, like everything in life ^_^

Comment: One of the undesirable consequences of using the notation $\ \tau(x)\ $ instead of something like  [HallaSurvivor's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/655547/hallasurvivor) $\ f_\tau\ $ is that it clashes with the definition of $\ \tau(x)\ $ when $\ \tau\ $ happens to be a function. This occurs when there is at most one $\ y\in F\ $ for each $\ x\in E\ $ such that $\ (x,y)\in\tau\ $.

Comment: The standard use of $\ \tau(x)\ $ in that case is to represent the unique $\ y\ $ (if it exists) such that $\ (x,y)\in\tau\ $. But the definition given in [jay shah's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/714437/jay-shah) question would make $ \tau(x)=\{y\}\ $, the singleton set containing $\ y\ $, instead of $ \tau(x)=y\ $, which is not quite the same thing.